# SQL: вставка в выборку правильного поля из множества

Tags: sql

У меня есть незатейливый запрос, который ищет дубликаты по ext_id:

```
SELECT s.ext_id, count(s.ext_id), s.id
FROM sale_point AS s
GROUP BY s.ext_id
HAVING count(s.ext_id) > 1;
```

Проблема в том, что на место s.id он подставляет первый найденный id, а мне нужен последний найденный (потом он участвует в дальнейших операциях скрипта).

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы на место s.id подставлялся id из последней найденной записи?

Пример:

В базе есть множество записей, среди них, допустим, две такие:

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | ext_id     |
+--------+------------+
| 376764 | 2065277658 |
+--------+------------+
| 390836 | 2065277658 |
+--------+------------+
```

Результатом выполнения скрипта в их отношении будет следующее:

```
+------------+-----------------+--------+
| ext_id     | count(s.ext_id) | id     |
+------------+-----------------+--------+
| 2065277658 |               2 | 376764 |
+------------+-----------------+--------+
```

То есть, в поле id будет отображён первый попавшийся id. А нужен последний.

Comment: Покажи: что в базе; что в результате запроса; как надо ...

Comment: Добавил в описание.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, запрос должен быть таким:

```
SELECT s.ext_id, count(s.ext_id), max(s.id)
FROM sale_point AS s
GROUP BY s.ext_id
HAVING count(s.ext_id) > 1
```